# Cannot send data to the server-side?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have the following code,

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  data: {
    'id': id
  },
  url: 'http::/localhost/my_project/controller/method',
  success: function(data) {
    swal({
      title: "Deleted",
      text: "The list has been deleted.",
      type: "success"
    },
    function(){
      location.reload();
    });
  },
  error: function(data) {
    swal("We cannot delete!", "The file is not deleted.", "error");
  }
});
```

Given the code, I'm trying to send a data in the background but it doesn't arrived at the controller's method.

Any Idea of the problem?

Comment: is it typo in url? `http::/` should be `http://`

Comment: You should start using your browsers development console (typically opened with F12). It allows you to do all kinds of debugging and inspection. For example it will show javascript errors and network requests done or not.

Comment: at backend what are you using?

Comment: I just mistakenly writting http:: in the question, but that is correct in my code. I'm using codeigniter as the backend framework. given the question above can send data using GET method but not using POST. Is there any other setting need to configure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:/* base url */ + "index.php/controller/method",
            data: {id:id },
            success: function(data) {    
        //success
            }
            });
```

Comment: `base_url` isn't a standard PHP function, codeigniter seems to use that function, please change it. Also it would be better if you'd format your code better.

Comment: Yeah that basically my code but the problem still persist

Comment: I did solve the problem, I try the test first by creating a simple example of how ajax works and apply again to codeigniter after finding solution, anyway thanks for the help.